# Replacing part of a query string in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm having trouble replacing part of a query string in jquery. When the user unfocuses from the input box, I want to clear out the search_rad portion of the query string so that duplicates don't occur (which is happening now).

HTML file

```
<input id="search_rad_input" type="number" placeholder="input search radius" />
<a id="getvol" data-href="?cmd=something=1&somethingelse=2">Click Me!</a>
```

JS File

```
$('#search_rad_input').focusout(function() {
    var input = $('#search_rad_input').val();
    var uri = $('#getvol').attr('data-href');
    $('#getvolresults').text( uri );
    $('#getvol').attr('data-href').replace('&search_rad=', "");
    var newuri = $('#getvol').attr('data-href', uri + "&search_rad=" + input);
});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tonyweed/83whn0y5/39/

Answer (score 0):

I think there is one spot where you have only **read** the `data-href` property, but you want to **replace** it. You have:

```
$('#getvol').attr('data-href').replace('&search_rad=', "");
```

I think you need:

```
var newAttrib = $('#getvol').attr('data-href').replace('&search_rad=', "");
$('#getvol').attr('data-href', newAttrib);
```